# VSTS Hosted Agent 2017 and PhantomJS Not working

Tags: phantomjs, .net-core, azure-devops, csproj

I'm migrating a project to dotnet core *.csproj on VSTS and I can't get a viable agent under Hosted2017 that has PhantomJS. Can anyone advise on this?

Neither the classic 'Hosted' or 'Hosted 2017' has PhantomJS explicitly as a capability.

It seems that it works on hosted by adding the following variable...

PHANTOMJS_BIN: C:\NPM\Modules\PhantomJS.cmd

but this is not correct for Hosted 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [npm install phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs) via **command line step/task** to install phantomjs package.

A simple sample to call phantomjs command:

1. Npm install (working folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory);` npm command: `install`; arguments: `phantomjs`.
2. Command line (Tool: `node_modules\.bin\phantomjs.cmd`; Arguments: `--help`; 
   Working directory: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`)

You also can add it to the environment **temporary** (Just in current session). For example:

1. Npm install (the same)
2. PowerShell script (Arguments: `-p $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\node_modules\.bin`;

Script:

```
Param(
 [string]$p
)
$env:Path += ";$p"
phantomjs --help
```

Comment: I used a variant of this - this is kind of the right answer but needs some tweaking. The correct npm module is now 'phantomjs-prebuilt' (the old one is depercated) and step 2 is not required. You can get around this by setting a variable of PHANTOMJS_BIN to '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\node_modules\.bin\phantomjs.cmd'